# What are the different types and error codes for NSURLSession/NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, cordova, nsurlconnection, ios11, xcode9

Why is the below error caused
?

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

What are the different types and error codes for `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection` ?

I could not get any specific documentation for this.

```
Environment -

Cordova - 7.1.0
Xcode - 9.0
ios - 11
```